# Pick color on color change (on sliding color wheel )

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, color-picker

I am using HSV color picker in swift it is working fine but the issue is it pick a color when I press the done button. I want to pick color instantly when it changes by the sliding wheel. but I don't know where can I find this color wheel sliding function

[image]

if someone has an idea how to achieve this please do let me know 
thanks in advance

Comment: Which library is that, `SwiftHSVColorPicker`?

Comment: yes SwiftHSVColorPicker

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong with the POD as when installing it through CocoaPods it suddenly gives some error like *Use of undeclared type SwiftHSVColorPicker.*

**Do a [manual installation](https://github.com/johankasperi/SwiftHSVColorPicker#installation)** as anyway the github project is not really updated frequently with the latest Swift changes and then you can work with it by this example of usage:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CustomSwiftHSVColorPickerDelegate {
    func colorDidChanged(currentColor: UIColor)
}

class CustomSwiftHSVColorPicker: SwiftHSVColorPicker{
    var delegate: CustomSwiftHSVColorPickerDelegate?

    override func hueAndSaturationSelected(_ hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat) {
        super.hueAndSaturationSelected(hue, saturation: saturation)
        self.delegate?.colorDidChanged(currentColor: self.color)
    }
    override func brightnessSelected(_ brightness: CGFloat) {
        super.brightnessSelected(brightness)
        self.delegate?.colorDidChanged(currentColor: self.color)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomSwiftHSVColorPickerDelegate {

    // Init ColorPicker with yellow
    var selectedColor: UIColor = UIColor.white

    // IBOutlet for the ColorPicker
    @IBOutlet var colorPicker: SwiftHSVColorPicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Setup Color Picker
        colorPicker.setViewColor(selectedColor)
    }

    func colorDidChanged(currentColor: UIColor) {
        print(currentColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: as you are selecting color on getSelectedColor button click . i just want to pick it when user change the color ... without pressing any button

Comment: I just updated my answer, I thought you couldn't get it work with the example, now should be meeting your expectation from your last comment. Now everytime the slider picker changes color the colorDidChanged function will hold the current color selected, and you could do whatever you would like with it, either change background color, save it in userdefaults, apply color in some uiview..

Comment: all set but give arror when i inherit CustomSwiftHSVColorPickerDelegate that it is undeclared type

Comment: I can build the code I pasted here in the answer fine. Try with a Project Clean and Project Rebuild by going to `Product -> Clean` and `Product -> Build`

Comment: i am unable to find SwiftHSVColorPicker  in subclass menu

Comment: Can you post some code, how are you implementing it?

Comment: i am trying to create classCustomSwiftHSVColorPicker with  subclass SwiftHSVColorPicker but it is not in subclass menu while creating

Comment: Have you tried copying (manual installation) the sources from SwiftHSVColorPicker instead of using it as a Pod? https://github.com/johankasperi/SwiftHSVColorPicker#installation

Comment: @GoalTech Anyhow the project is not maintained a lot. So do a manual installation of the pod by copying the sources (files) needed for the functionality in your project and then apply the custom picker like above. You will be fine with this.

Comment: Upload it to a github repo and share it here. To chat overstackoverflow you must have at least 20 reputation so I can't invite you to a chat